# Proving linearity of map when scalar multiplication defined differently on domain and codomain

Tags: linear-algebra

For $T:V \rightarrow W$, to prove $T$ is linear, we show that for $v_1, v_2 \in V$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$, that $T(v_1+ \lambda v_2) = T(v_1) + \lambda T(v_2)$, where $\lambda T(v_2)$ denotes standard scalar multiplication.

But now suppose I have $V$ and its complex conjugate vector space $\overline{V}$, where $\overline{V}$ is the same as $V$ except that scalar multiplication is defined as $\overline{S}(\lambda, v_1) = S(\overline{\lambda}, v_1)$, where $S$ is the normal scalar multiplication on $V$, and $\overline{S}$ is the scalar multiplication on the complex conjugate vector space and $v_1 \in V$

Here, if we wanted to show $T:V \rightarrow \overline{V'}$ is linear, where $V'$ denotes the dual space of $V$, under which definition of scalar multiplication do we have to show that $T(\lambda v_1) = \lambda T(v_1)$? Is it the standard scalar multiplication for $T(\lambda v_1)$ and the complex conjugate scalar multiplication for $\lambda T(v_1)$?

Comment: If $\mu_V\colon \mathbb{C}\times V\to V$ is scalar multiplication in $V$, and $\mu_W\colon\mathbb{C}\times W\to W$ is scalar multiplication on $W$, what you want to show is that $T(\mu_V(\lambda,v)) = \mu_W(\lambda,T(v))$. So you would use the "standard" multiplication to calculate $\lambda v_1$ and then apply $T$ to that; then calculate $T( v_1)$, and use the complex conjugate scalar multiplication to compute $\lambda T(v_1)$. Compare the results.

Comment: In particular, your first paragraph is inaccurate; "$\lambda T(v_2)$" does not denote "standard scalar multiplication", it denotes whatever the scalar multiplication happens to be in $W$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you. That was the clarification I required.